# Displaying a String on GUI with QT

Tags: qt

I'm trying to display a string through a serial port on GUI using QT.
The computer displays strange characters like these ~S~R��~~S~R��~~S~ and not the message that is supposed to be sent from the mote.The data comes from a Z1 mote which uses the data encoding format JSON. I think it should be a problem of type conversion.
Here is the code of the slot to display the message:

```
void MainWindow::receive()
{
    QByteArray data = port.readAll();

    QString command(data)  ;

    ui->textEdit_Status->insertPlainText(command);
}
```

Edit: Hex output from OP:

```
7e530002000061127e7e52ef817e
```

Comment: How could we help you without knowing anything _at all_ about the data you're talking about? Please [edit] your question to explain where it comes from and how it is encoded.

Comment: `QString command(data);` looks too unspecific. What’s the encoding of the data you receive? Does it contain binary data/unprintable characters? Then data.toHex() is possibly what you want to display for debugging.

Comment: By default QString for const char* and QByteArray will use QString::fromAscii for Qt4 and QString::fromUtf8 for Qt5 - in case of Qt4 fromAscii will use codec set by QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings() or QString::fromLatin1 if no codec is set

Comment: The data returned by `port.readAll()` is not what you think it is. Add a `qDebug() << data;` as the 2nd line of the body of `receive`, and you'll see that you're receiving junk. Probably your port settings are wrong.

Comment: @Francis I deleted my answer because this doesn't seem to be a problem with string encoding on the receiver side. You wrote: "I tried the same Qt code with another Z1 mote which is uploaded with a program which measures the temperature, and the temperature values were successfully displayed on the GUI. So I think that the serial parameters are the same on sending and receiving side." I wouldn't place my bet on the last sentence as long as you didn't explicitely set the parameters on both sides prior to sending/receiving.

Comment: @Murphy ok supposed that is the problem. How should I proceed ? Sorry for annoying you by such questions but all this stuff is new for me and thank you for your answers.